# MS Access Records keep appearing as #Deleted

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, corruption

I have inherited a large network database written in Access 2010 VBA.
it is split into front and back ends with users of approx 100 but about 5-10 concurrent.
The #Deleted (across all fields) record appears only in one table which has a primary key of Long Int and records around the 100k range.

The table doesn't have any relationships so cascade protection isn't the issue.

Every few days a record shows up as #deleted which then prevents a form linked to the table (dynaset) from showing its records.

Compact and repair does remove the #deleted records but also removes the primary key for the table so that has to be reapplied before saving.

This leads me to believe the record corruption is also effecting the index of the table.

Then again a few days later the same scenario.

I have recreated the table from scratch replicating the PK and indexes and transferring the data across but no luck.

i know running concurrent users can cause data corruption but this application has ran for years without this situation happening so i cant believe that its suddenly become a problem.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening? or ideas on how to narrow down the potential issues?

Comment: First of all, how are records deleted?  Is there a macro or VBA code behind the functionality, or are all users using a basic Access form and/or datasheet view with default functionality for deletion?  The database was perhaps "written" in Access 2010, but do all possible 100 users have the same 2010 version?  Running for years does not matter if so many users might have disparate versions of Access which have certainly changed within that amount of time.

Comment: Hiya records are deleted via a datasheet view with default deletion. i can say with certainty all users have have the same version of access.

Comment: Build an audit table and triggers (I believe 2010 has triggers, is that correct?) and determine which user login `Environ("username")` is deleting the record and work from there.

Comment: You can also see if your users are trying to use a short cut to make the screen size smaller (ctrl + -). This is a short cut in Access to delete the current record on the form...

Comment: A web search for "access primary key lost on compact" reveals that similar table corruption is not uncommon, however neither the source of the corruption nor the solutions are clear.  I'll not waste time re-sharing random websites, but suggest further searches on your own.  Various pages might not match your situation exactly, but if you have enough patience to read through, you might find subtle similarities and find some hints of possible causes and/or solutions.

Comment: Is the Primary Key an AutoNumber field?  If so, the Autonumber seed value can become corrupt.  I have experience where a compact/repair fixed this problem, but I have also had to completely redefine the Autonumber field to resolve such a problem.  Recreating it can be a real problem if the field is used in any way to reference the table rows (either with an actual Access relationship or just as a manual reference #).

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, @ C Perkins I have searched many of the same articles im sure you came across and tried multiple solutions however with no luck I decided to stop semi blindly trying similar resolutions and see if anyone has had the same issue. 
The PK is an AutoNum I had a feeling it was something like this so I created a new clone table and just transferred the data across so the key index would be new for the same data but no luck...